# Trying to increase nginx buffer

Tags: nginx

I have the nginx server running fine with this config.

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

    }

}
```

but when I try and modify buffer size it fails.

```
server {
    location / {
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

    }


}
```

I get this error

```
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "client_header_buffer_size" directive is not allowed here
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I went ahead and put in the error

Comment: Error message clearly states what's wrong. Check documentation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `client_header_buffer_size` is not available within the "location" context. You'll also need to move the `large_client_header_buffers` Move them to within the "server" context and it'll work.

```
server {
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    location / {
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_max_body_size 8m;            
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_buffer_size